# Does jQuery Ajax call only for the HTML or also the images styles and scripts inside the page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, stylesheet

I make a [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html"
})
```

to a page that has styles and scripts linked.

If in the current page I don't append those but only some specific div (from the ajax result) which might have images but not styles and scripts,
will the styles and scripts (in head or footer) be called and thus make use of bandwidth?

The question is: if I call for the HTML and don't append the `<link href="...">` inside it will the stylesheet (/scripts) be called & received? Will the Browser call them only if I append them in the current DOM?

Comment: not able to understand your question

Comment: This will fetch the whole content of the test.html

Comment: The question is if I call for the HTML and don't append the <link href="..."> will the stylesheet (/scripts) be called & received? Will these be called only if I append them in the current DOM?

Comment: Nothing will be loaded except of page HTML until you append it. You can check the result of the request just making it from dev tools - http://take.ms/Avanm

Comment: Thanks @VasiliyGorokhov if you could elaborate it a bit and put it in an answer I'll accept it :)